# Kdevelop over SSHFS sometimes stutters last few lines on save?

Tags: editors, sshfs

Sometimes, but not always, a certain file, when saved with Kdevelop over SSHFS to a remote server, will include the last n lines of the file repeated. N is variable from save to save. The file that gets committed is as if a user took a random selection from the bottom of the file, and pasted it again right afterwards.

An example:

This is what shows in the editor to the user (last 3 lines):

```
   </div><!-- END Header -->
<div id="MainWrapper">
```

This is what gets committed to the server on save:

```
   </div><!-- END Header -->
<div id="MainWrapper">- END Header -->
<div id="MainWrapper">
```

It seems that if a given file, under given circumstances is a "stutter" file, it will almost always stutter that file when saved by that user from that client computer. But if a file is not a stutter file under given circumstances, it will not become one.

For a given file on the same server, it may stutter save for one user but not for a different user.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to prevent it.

Comment: Perhaps KDevelop has a problem with end-of-buffer (EOB) pointer during writing?  The example you gave suggests a line or more was deleted, moving the EOB backwards as expected, but the write routine is remembering the initial size?  Could you try saving the file, observing the 'stutter', adding a line (a comment), saving again, check for stutter or differences in output file.  Perhaps even delete a line, see if stutter increases or decreases/improves.